# Streamreader - reading data from IP

Tags: vb.net, streamreader, readline

I am interfacing an instrument that sends data via IP. I want to put my reading code in a timer to read the data in the background while the user interacts with the program. My problem is that it appears streamreader readline blocks. Is that true? If so how should I go about reading a line from the input device with out blocking?

I should also note my streamreader is a Networkstream. Also the target framework is Net 2.0. Not sure if that is important or not.

TIA,
John

Comment: Either don't use `ReadLine` or else call `ReadLine` from another thread.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude.  I really am curious.  Why TIA?  I've never understood the reasoning behind saying "Thanks in Advance".  It's always seemed more rude than anything, like "I've already thanked you, so don't expect thanks when you actually do help me".  Is it just me?  Abbreviating it to TIA just seems to be icing on the cake.  Don't get me wrong.  I'm assuming you didn't intend to be rude at all, I've just always thought it was an odd thing to say.  In any case, saying thanks or putting your name at the end of your question is frowned upon.  See the [faq] for more details.

Comment: Point well taken, thanks.

Comment: @StevenDoggart - I consider TIA to be polite, thanking someone in advance for taking the time to help out. Either way it is not needed on this site.

Comment: @MattWilko Wouldn't you just say "Thanks", then?  Why the "In Advance"?  :)

Comment: By the way, John, did you follow what I meant in my first comment or did I just confuse you?

Comment: @StevenDoggart - You don't know at the time of writing whether someone will reply or not, so it is thanks in advance of someone possibly replying at some point in the future. Idiosyncratic English politeness maybe?

Comment: @MattWilko No, I still don't get it.  But thanks for trying to explain it.  But I'm sure it's due to my own mental shortcomings, not because of any failure on your part :)

Comment: @StevenDoggart - "It is perfectly suitable for business contexts." but "you should also extend proper thanks after help has been provided" source: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49218/can-thanks-in-advance-be-considered-rude

Comment: Hi Steven, I did get your point and I want to follow the guidelines for this forum. I appreciate and value all comments and the opportunity to learn form others.

Comment: @MattWilko Seems like the consensus on that page is generally in my favor, or at least that's how I choose to interpret it.  You're welcome in advance :)

Comment: @JohnLee were you able to solve your problem?  I didn't want to leave you high and dry with nothing to show for it except a spectacularly superfluous discussion about TIA :)

Comment: Hi Steven - I have not solved my problem. I was hoping to see some discussion about the question also.

Answer (score 0):

`StreamReader.ReadLine` is a blocking (synchronous) method.  When you call it, it will block execution from continuing until a complete line has been received.  That makes it much easier to work with, but obviously, if you need it to work asynchronously, it doesn't meet your needs.

The `StreamReader` contains both blocking and asynchronous versions of many of it's methods.  For instance, in addition to the `ReadLine` method, there is also a `ReadLineAsync` method which does the same thing as `ReadLine`, but it does so asynchronously.

So, the choice you have is, either you need to use one of the asynchronous methods, or you can continue to use the `ReadLine` method, even though it is a blocking method, as long as you call it from another thread.  If it blocks a background thread, whose sole purpose is to read the stream, that doesn't really matter to you, as long as the UI thread isn't blocked.  So for instance, you could have a method like this:

```
Private Sub MonitorStream
    While True
        ProcessLine(_Reader.ReadLine)
    End While
End Sub
```

Then, you can call that method in a new thread, like this:

```
Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf MonitorStream)
t.Start()
```

That's just a simple example.  You'd probably want to check if the stream is open rather than just looping infinitely, etc.  But that should give you a starting point.  I'd say that using the `ReadLineAsync` method would probably be preferable, but for someone who is knew to asynchronous programming, the infinite loop in a separate thread is easier to work with and understand.

Comment: Thanks Steve that is exactly what I was needing to understand. One problem still, I do not see the ReadLineAsynch as a member of StreamReader. I open StreamReader on a NetworkStream. I am working with .Net 2.0 in VS2008 - is that a problem?

Comment: Hi Steve - The treading example you gave will do the job. I appreciate your time and knowledge.

Comment: One more question, Steve. If I use an infinite loop in the thread, will the thread close when the program closes? I ask because when I run debug mode and exit the program in VS, it still remains in debugging mode until I click the Stop Debugging button. Sorry if these are silly questions but threading is all new to me.

Comment: Yes, it is my understanding that if it is a background thread (which they are by default), then they will not stop the application from stopping.  If a thread is set as a foreground thread, the application will not completely stop until the extra foreground thread is also terminated.  You could also always call `Thread.Abort`.  As far as the Async methods go, it's true, those did not exist in .NET 2.0.  So, if you wanted to use explicitly async methods, you'd have to use the ones available on the `NetworkStream` itself and forgo using the `StreamReader` at all.